# Linux - Setting root password caused "strange" behavior I want to revert back to normal

Tags: linux

I am relatively new to Linux. I'm running CrounchBang, a Debian distro as my personal workstation. It's not a server.
Here is my problem:

I wanted to change a password for myself (user) by typing: sudo passwd
Then it prompted me for user name and I thought I had to input root so I can get the right to change user password. I was wrong. Anyway, I changed a password for root.

I didn't loose or forget it so I can still do everything I want.. or so I think.. but now I notice "strange" behavior.

For example, I can not Power off sing Super-X -> Power off as I could before. It just says it's shutting down but does nothing. I have to use terminal: poweroff, then it prompts for root password, and only then it shuts down.

Another example is typing "login" into terminal. It responds with: login: Cannot possibly work without effective root

Being new to linux it's hard for me to remember exactly how it behaved before I set the root password but some things are definitely "weird" now.

Can anyone explain this to me or point to a solution? If possible with no workarounds (like adding myself to sudoers), I'd like to get it back to normal (default) behavior.

Comment: ask @ http://superuser.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not aware of any problems that unlocking root may lead you to (in fact, I've done it many times without any unpleasant consequences), but you can always revert the changes by issuing this command: `sudo passwd -dl root`

Comment: If you are not aware I won't event try to understand. But your help is greatly appreciated, it worked perfectly! Thanks